# Media Foundation Movie Playback: Disable Pitch Preservation / Stretching

Tags: windows

As mentioned in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155028/qmediaplayer-setplaybackrate-1-causes-high-pitched-audio), Media Foundation attempts to preserve the pitch of the audio when the rate is not 1.0.

I would like to disable this feature in Media Foundation so that it behaves just as Direct Show does: when you increase playback above a rate of 1.0, the audio pitch increases, when you go below 1.0 it decreases.

On macOS you can control this with AVFoundation's QTMovieRateChangesPreservePitchAttribute setting as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563448/slow-down-playback-speed/3568927#3568927).

Does anyone know how to do this with Media Foundation?